# I am not getting my text and scroll images side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a code for "Contact us" page of our website. Now I want my details on the left side and the address map (which i copied from google maps) on the right side of the website. But the map image is on the top side of the page and the details on the bottom of it. How can i resolve this??

Here's the code:

```
<html> 
    <div class="scroll">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>

    <address style="font-weight: bold">
        <h4>     "   "  </h4>
        <h4>Mark Doug</h4>
        <p><a href=" ">Mark.doug2010@abcd.in</a></p>
        <p>H-445,Silver square street<br /> </p>
        <p> CA</p>
    </address>

    <style>
    .scroll{
        overflow:scroll;
        width:500px;
        height:357px;
        margin-left:682px;
        margin-bottom:700px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    .child{width:1000px;height:1000px;background-image:url(vit.png);}
    </style>
</html>
```

Also, when i try to get the "vit.png" image to top, the text automatically goes to the bottom side.

I have tried putting div `class="scroll"` inside the address tag but still the same result.

Comment: use css `float:left|right`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: can you try creating a fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/3n4xE/embedded/result/ ? if yes go here http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/3n4xE/

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/3n4xE/1/

Comment: That jsfiddle is working fine for your address, but when i  want to put my personal address map link on it, it stops showing the map at all. Why??  This Link:  https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Vellore+Institute+of+Technology/@12.971716,79.159594,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x3bad479f0ccbe067:0xfef222e5f36ecdeb   It stops showing the map at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css rule `.element {float:left}` but also specify a width because by default your content width is 100%. so it should be something like `.element {width:400px; float:left}`

Hope it helps